# Entity Framework returns InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a groupby query, using odata v4, with efcore (.net 5), but i'm having this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.

```
    [HttpPost("odata/v1/Infraccion/InfraccionesConsultadas")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult InfraccionesConsultadas()
    {
        //_repository.GetAll() returns an IQueryable
        return Ok(_repository.GetAll());
    }
```

This is the url with query parameters

```
/odata/v1/Infraccion/InfraccionesConsultadas?$apply=compute(year(FechaHora)%20as%20y)/groupby((y))
```

Besides this, i'm not having problems, for example, when i filter:
/odata/v1/Infraccion/InfraccionesConsultadas?$filter=Lugar eq 'TEST'

Any ideas of what may be happening?

Edit:
This is the parent class from the repository that i'm using

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T, TContext> : IRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : Model where TContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly TContext _context;

        public BaseRepository(TContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll(bool getDeleted = false)
        {
            try
            {
                DbSet<T> source = _context.Set<T>();
                return (!getDeleted) ? source.Where((T item) => item.IsDeleted == false) : source.Select((T item) => item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Couldn't retrieve entities: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

      //...
       
}
```

Comment: You aren't showing any of the repository logic or the DbContext. Without additional details it is impossible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @DavidL I added code from repository. GetAll() method It's straight inherited from parent

Answer (score 0):

It's due to IQueryable result with customize function called.

Looks like you need to add AsEnumerable() or ToList()

```
return Ok(_repository.GetAll().ToList());
```